# Why is this dry pepper fruit still "powered"?

Tags: botany

Check out this photo of my pepper plant this cloudy morning: (click for full res)
[image]

Usually (and this can be seen on 2 and a half of the 4 fruits in this pic) the fruits are "disconnected" from the plant's juice flow when they're ripe. Then the fruit starts to dry. Yet the middle one in the pic is dry while its "cord" is still green (literally). Why does it not become dry like his fellows do?

There's also another interesting situation going on with the lower right fruit's "cord", which is half-dry. I wonder why it has been like this for a little over a month now without change.

The lighting conditions are pretty poor for this plant, so I use a 40 watt incandescent lamp for it and 4 other plants 24/7.

<sub>Please, excuse my poor vocabulary :)</sub>

Comment: The fruit in the middle had his "cord" completely dried out this week, but the weird lower-right half-powered pepper is still like this. I decided to remove them all and I didn't take a pic, which I regret now. It could have been an interesting visual addition.

Comment: probably because of the way sunlight falls on them.. the part that receives more sunlight dries out faster than the others. Please check if the sunlight received is uniform all over.

Comment: @TheLastWord  makes sense. The sun is blocked by a few leaves for the left peppers. I suppose it must be the reason.

Comment: that is the obvious reason.. might be some   biological processes too, but this could be the major contributor.

Comment: It might be *a potential* reason, but certainly not the *obvious* reason.